# setText() not working on inflated textview

Tags: android, android-inflate

I have a textview but it is not located in the activity main layout `xml`  that is set by`setContentView()` method  but it is located in other `xml` file, so i used an inflater but it doesn't work! 
This is my code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = 
(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.anotherXMLfile, null);
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText("something");
```

Please help me!

Comment: Show the whole class code. Edit your question!

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the view. Like

setView(view);

or

setContentView(view);

Comment: setContentView(view) give an error while setView is unrecognized. Maybe there are other methods to set a inflater view?

Comment: You will have to write as : yourContext.setContentView(view);

Comment: Ok i have done, it worksssssss, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

settext in TextView and setContentView in activity

Add xml file in your main layout like:

```
<include layout="@layout/your_xml_file_name" />
```

than you can directly call TextView id and use it.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

or
TextView textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
textView.setText("Write Your Content");
```

Comment: I setted the setContentView in onCreate method. Have I to set the inflater view? What method have I to use?